# Unable to Launch Hive prompt in Windows 10

Tags: hadoop, hive, derby

I have downloaded Hadoop 3.1.0 and Hive is 2.1.0 in my Windows 10. I have Hadoop running properly using start-all.cmd command from terminal. When I try to run 'hive' from command prompt it gives following messages and errors which are in the attached screenshot. I am using Derby 10.12.1.1 with hive. Following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=npyRXkMhrgk) from Youtube.

[image]

Have also tried reinstalling Hive but still not working. I have already spent a lot of my time dealing with this problem but got no success.
Any sort of help will be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: By looking at the error, seems you are not authorized

Comment: Please post the hive configuration files and the output of `jps` command

Comment: @franklinsijo This is output of jps command.

'1808 NodeManager
800 ResourceManager
4232 NetworkServerControl
3148 NameNode
7868 Jps'

Comment: This is pseudo distributed cluster, correct? Datanode and secondary namenode are not running! Can you post your hadoop and hive configuration files?

Comment: @franklinsijo Yes its a pseudo distributed cluster. Here is my latest output of JPS. Datanode did not start in it for some unknown reason but its running now.

7108 NameNode
8616 NodeManager
10796 Jps
12284 ResourceManager
1644 DataNode
8940 NetworkServerControl

Comment: @franklinsijo which Hive conf files do u want me to upload here exactly ?

Comment: `hive-site.xml`

Comment: @franklinsijo Please visit this google doc link to find my hdfs-site.xml. Thanks.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1kBmvQhFxx16HjTm47HMRQck_q98oCJJJ_qkUtzwIWy8/edit?usp=sharing